# PHP places variable outside string

Tags: php, html, variables, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a **Wordpress template** with project teasers. 
Using Advanced Custom Fields in the admin a color can be picked to style the teaser. 
The problem I'm facing is that my #hex color value is placed outside of the string as text.

My PHP:

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
      $catname =$category->cat_name;
      $hex = the_field("project_teaser_color");
      echo '<h3 color:"' . $hex .'">' . $catname . '</h3>'; } 
?>
```

The Output:

```
"#5c1929"
<h3 color:"">Branding</h3>
"#5c1929"
<h3 color:"">Website</h3>
```

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/the_field-vs-get_field/

Comment: `<h3 style="color:pink;">Branding</h3>`

Comment: Thanks @deceze that fixed the problem!